# Why annotate generates duplicate entries?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given the following code:

```
payments = Payment.objects.filter(
        customer=self.customer,
        created_at__gte=kwargs['start_date'],
        created_at__lte=kwargs['end_date']
    ).order_by('-date')

balance = payments.values('currency').annotate(Sum('amount'))

> print(balance)
> [{'amount__sum': Decimal('0.00'), 'currency': 'USD'},
   {'amount__sum': Decimal('0.00'), 'currency': 'USD'},
   {'amount__sum': Decimal('9000.00'), 'currency': 'SEK'},
   {'amount__sum': Decimal('45000.00'), 'currency': 'EUR'},
   {'amount__sum': Decimal('11385.00'), 'currency': 'SEK'}]
```

List of payments for this customer:

```
> print(payments)
> ('-1487.50', 'USD')
('1487.50', 'USD')
('-3663.72', 'USD')
('3663.72', 'USD')
('15000.00', 'EUR')
('9000.00', 'SEK')
('30000.00', 'EUR')
('9865.00', 'SEK')
('1520.00', 'SEK')
```

If I use aggregate, I get the Sum, but for all currencies and that's not what I want. I must be able to split into currencies.

```
{'amount__sum': Decimal('65385.00')}
```

I am trying to extract the payments by customer grouping and summing by currencies. However what happens is that it doesn't Sum some of the values instead duplicating them. Any ideas?

Comment: Which of the user's payments are in the specified date range?

Comment: I have printed the list of the payments that should be Summed in the question. It should include all payments from all currencies in that date range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the `order_by` that causes this.  Fields mentioned in `order_by` will implicitly be part of the group otherwise defined as the fields mentioned in `values` according to the [docs on aggregation and order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by).

See if

```
Payment.objects.filter(
        customer=self.customer,
        created_at__gte=kwargs['start_date'],
        created_at__lte=kwargs['end_date']
    ).values('currency').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

won't give you exactly the answer you are looking for.

This will also be caused by a default ordering set on `Payment.Meta.ordering`.  If you did that you will need to cancel out the ordering explicitly like so:

```
Payment.objects.filter(
        customer=self.customer,
        created_at__gte=kwargs['start_date'],
        created_at__lte=kwargs['end_date']
    ).order_by().values('currency').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: I tried to remove as you stated but didn't work. I had a `meta` attribute setting the order. I had to override my query by setting a blank `.order_by()` as they indeed mention here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values
Please edit your answer and add this possibility aswell. I'll mark as the correct one. :-)