# Order Django queryset by related field (with code-value)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Simplifying my model a lot, I have the following:

```
class Player(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.IntegerField()


class Statistic(models.Model):
    '''
    Known codes are:
        - goals
        - assists
        - red_cards
    '''

    # Implicit ID
    player = models.ForeignKey(
        'Player', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='statistics')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

I'm using a code-value strategy to add different statistics in the future, without the need of adding new fields to the model.

Now, I want to list all the players, so my question is:

Is there any way to order the players by their goals scored, for example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use annotate with conditional `Case` statement.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, Value, IntegerField

Statistic.objects.all().annotate(
    goals=Case(
        When(code="goals", then=F("value")),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )).order_by("-goals")
```

Your queryset has now additional field `goals` which is equal to `value` only if `code == goals`, otherwise it is equal to 0. All i had to do from now was to order by this field.

Comment: Thanks, but in your answer you're not ordering the Players, right? You're actually ordering the Statistics, which is not what I needed.

Comment: I see that using my approach, my queryset gets 3 times bigger (one time per each different code?). Do you know why is that?

Comment: You must apply order_by() to your queryset. It is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37563194/9905068 and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by:

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Daniel Kusy's answer, I found the inspiration to do some small modifications for my specific scenario, where ordering Players by their scored goals would be like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, Value, IntegerField

Players.objects.all().annotate(
    goals=Case(
        When(statistics__code="goals", then=F("statistics__value")),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )).order_by("-goals")
```

Comment: But now my queryset seems to get 3 times bigger (one time per each code?). Why is that?