# Django annotate and aggregate not suport Timefild for sum

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-annotate, django-aggregation

How can I make the total time sum of each user being that annotate and aggregate have no support for Timefild

Models:

```
class Pireps(models.Model):
    ...
    flight_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
```

Views:

```
def flight(request):
    ...
    flight_time =  Pireps.objects.annotate(total_time =(Sum('flight_time')).order_by('total_time)
```

| id | date create | flight time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22/10/22 | 01:10:00 |
| 1 | 22/10/22 | 01:50:00 |
| 1 | 22/10/22 | 00:40:00 |
| 2 | 22/10/22 | 00:50:00 |
| 2 | 22/10/22 | 00:50:00 |
| 3 | 22/10/22 | 01:20:00 |

output of the result wanted like this

| id | flight time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03:00:00 |
| 2 | 01:40:00 |
| 3 | 00:40:00 |

Comment: The same id occurs multiple times?

Comment: Read more about duplicate rows here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562420/why-annotate-generates-duplicate-entries

Comment: I want to group by user ID and total sum of hours